# Why I cannot do this in SSMS directly? (assigning a LOGIN to a USER)

Tags: sql-server, security, users, logins

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I want to change the LOGIN for a USER in a database.

FROM THIS:

[image]

TO THIS:

[image]

Initially, the database has the [...] dots option to change this greyed-out (why?):

The only way to do this I found, was to do it via T-SQL:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'usera', 'loginnew';
```

Why could I not be able to do this directly in SSMS?

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, the only possible answer is because Microsoft didn't build the capacity to make it happen. It's not the only thing that is only available through T-SQL commands. There are lots and lots of others. You're going to find that the GUI only gets you so far.

Comment: Do it from the login instead of the user

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher please elaborate

Comment: In the login (Security->Logins), you have a "User Mapping" section where your login is "linked" to the user. You will have to remove the user from the previous login and then you will be able to add it to the new login. You will then have to set the permission back